# query = query.OrderBy(p => p.IsTop).ThenOrderByDescending(p => p.JobId)?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I want to sort objects by `IsTop` property ascending and then by `JobId` property descending:

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.IsTop).ThenOrderByDescending(p => p.JobId);
```

How do I do this? I know the reverse:

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(p => p.IsTop).ThenBy(p=>p.JobId)
```

Syntax works but it's not what I want. What I want is actually whatever situation is the `IsTop` items will be at the top!

Comment: Does query = query.OrderBy(p => p.IsTop).ThenByDescending(p => p.JobId) not work?

Answer (score 3):

Bool sorted in ascending order is false, true.

Try:
query.OrderByDescending(p => p.IsTop).ThenByDescending(p => p.JobId);

Answer (score 2):

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.IsTop).ThenByDescending(p => p.JobId);
```